# Хендлеры в pytelegrambotapi для бота в ТГ

Tags: python, telebot

Всем привет, прошу объяснить мне про хендлеры `@bot.message_handler` для бота и какие они есть, можно ли делать любые названия для них и тд?

Comment: А почитать документацию для библиотеки? Или любой учебник по Python раздел декораторы

Comment: названия функции под декоратором может быть любым, по факту хендлер - это привязка типа `что делать, если боту поступил тот или иной тип сообщения или команды`, следовательно хендлеры могут обрабатывать как определенный текст, вид текста, так и команды

Answer (score 1):

**@bot.message_handler** по своей сути явяется декоратором для функции, в качестве аргумента для которого даётся фильтр отбора входящих сообщений. Тоесть, каждый раз когда боту приходит сообщение, он проверяет проходит оно по фильтрам или нет. Если подходит - запускает декорируемую функцию. [Здесь](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#message-handlers) можно прочитать об этом подробнее и посмотреть примеры работы этого декоратора (En)